# How to group a dataframe by a column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

So I have this dataframe here. I want to make a pie chart of the countries that come up the most. In order for me to get my labeling correct, I need to create a list called 'countries' that begin with the country that appears most and end with countries that appear once. How would I do that exactly?

[image]

Comment: To clarify, I would want ITA to start the list since it comes up the most times. But what if ITA started 2nd. How would I write that? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) which sorted by default, so get indices and convert them to list:

```
countries = df["Nationality"].value_counts().index.tolist()
```

Comment: you're the best!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got you well, but maybe this is a solution:

> df = sorted(your_df, key = your_df.loc[:, ["Nationality"]].count,
> reverse = True)

Your problem is something about sorting elements by frequency